# Custom ImageView not recognizing OnTouchEvent

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

I created a very simple ImageView and I am trying to implement OnTouchEvent(). This app is being developed in Xamarin, so it is in C#.

It does not look like my OnTouchEvent is firing properly when I add the CustomImageView to the layout.

**How can I alter my code to register OnTouchEvents?**

Side note: I would like to develop something that allows the user to scale/rotate/move the created imageview, so if I am off track let me know what I should be looking to do.

**CustomImageView**

```
    public class CustomImageView : ImageView
{
    private float _viewX;


    public CustomImageView (Context context) :
        base(context)
    {
        Initialize ();
    }

    public CustomImageView (Context context, IAttributeSet attrs) :
        base (context, attrs)
    {
        Initialize ();
    }

    public CustomImageView (Context context, IAttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) :
        base (context, attrs, defStyle)
    {
        Initialize ();
    }

    void Initialize ()
    {
    }

    public bool OnTouchEvent(MotionEvent m_event){



        switch (m_event.Action) {

        case MotionEventActions.Down:
            _viewX = m_event.GetX ();
            System.Console.WriteLine ("Down");
            break;

        case MotionEventActions.Up:
            System.Console.WriteLine ("Up");
            break;

        case MotionEventActions.Move:
            //int x_cord = (int)m_event.GetX;
        //  int y_cord = (int)m_event.GetY;
            System.Console.WriteLine ("Move");
            break;

        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

**Here is the button that creates the CustomImageView and add it to the current Layout**

```
            btnAddImage2.Click += (sender, e) => 
        { 
            CustomImageView bitmapView = new CustomImageView (this);
            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.DecodeResource(Resources, Resource.Drawable.PixagramLogo);
            bitmapView.SetImageBitmap(bitmap);
            m_Layout.AddView (bitmapView);

        };
```

**FIXED/SOLVED**

It appears I needed to override the method. Seems like a fix for my immediate problem.

```
        public override bool OnTouchEvent(MotionEvent m_event){



        switch (m_event.Action) {

        case MotionEventActions.Down:
            _viewX = m_event.GetX ();
            System.Console.WriteLine ("Down");
            break;

        case MotionEventActions.Up:
            System.Console.WriteLine ("Up");
            break;

        case MotionEventActions.Move:
            //int x_cord = (int)m_event.GetX;
        //  int y_cord = (int)m_event.GetY;
            System.Console.WriteLine ("Move");
            break;

        }
        return true;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    public override bool OnTouchEvent(MotionEvent m_event){



    switch (m_event.Action) {

    case MotionEventActions.Down:
        _viewX = m_event.GetX ();
        System.Console.WriteLine ("Down");
        break;

    case MotionEventActions.Up:
        System.Console.WriteLine ("Up");
        break;

    case MotionEventActions.Move:
        //int x_cord = (int)m_event.GetX;
    //  int y_cord = (int)m_event.GetY;
        System.Console.WriteLine ("Move");
        break;

    }
    return true;
}
```